# Prevent code from happening until

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a game, but my character is allowed to move on the title screen (if I use the keys to move him, and then press "`Play`", the character will already be moved to a different location.) I thought that I should create a variable called "`CanMove`", set it to false, and eventually set it to true when I press the "`Play`" button. However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I put this code all the way at the end of the document (but still in the `$(document).ready` part):

```
if (canMove === true) {
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
           case 65: //if LEFT direction pressed down:
             walkLeft();
             break;
           case 83: //if DOWN direction pressed down:
           $('#character').animate({top: "+=18px"}, 0.1);
             rightCharacter()
             changeRightCharacter();
             break;
           case 87: //if UP direction pressed down:
             jumpUp();      
             break;
           case 68: //if RIGHT direction pressed down:
             walkRight();
             break;
           default:
             break;
        }
    });
}
```

You see, I set canMove to true when I press the button (the code for the button is above the code I pasted here, though), yet it still won't work. I think it is because the document already checks if canMove is true or false once it loads, and it doesn't make a difference if you set it to true or false after it loads. I don't know how to change that, so I'd appreciate any help!

PS: I would also like the ability to prevent the character from moving later in the game (i.e. during textboxes, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `if` inside the `keydown` handler. This way, the document will detect keys always, but only respond to them if `canMove` is set.

Regarding "I don't know what I'm doing wrong"... yes, you do, you describe it perfectly in your paragraph below the code: you test `canMove` only once at the start, and decide whether to set a `keydown` handler or not depending on that. If you don't set it, the document won't listen for keydowns ever again (unless you're also setting it from somewhere else in the code); if you do, then it will listen for keydowns forever (unless you are removing the handler somewhere else in the code).